# Compiz in Arch Linux, no window title available?

Tags: arch-linux, compiz

I already enabled emerald as the window decoration provider command, and I have a theme configured for emerald.

But when I start compiz by `compiz --replace`, I get no window title bar. Is there something I forgot to configure?

Comment: IIRC from my days playing with Compiz, you need to run a separate window decorator, like `gtk-window-decorator` for example.

Comment: @jw013: [Apparently, that's what emerald should do](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz#Initial_configuration); but still (@warl0ck), have you tried `emerald --replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed `emerald` and enabled Window decorator in `ccsm`, the title bar emerged.